# Python virtualenvwrapper executable does not exist

Tags: python, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

Im using Python 2.7 on mac with anaconda, and Im trying to set up a virtualenv with virtualenvwrapper.  I have downloaded virtualenvwrapper via `sudo pip install virtualenvwrapper` but there is no `virtualenvwrapper.sh` in `/usr/local/bin` .

I cant figure out what Im missing?

Comment: What does your terminal return when you give the command ```virtualenvwrapper```

Comment: Wait, if you're using Anaconda why are you running `sudo pip install` and expecting installation into `/usr/local/bin`?  Are you trying to use virtualenvwrapper with anaconda or not?  Also, you're not using the OSX system Python are you?

Comment: i found it in anaconda, thank you